# GoogleApps java client information

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

I am in a way of writing the java client on GoogleApps for managing the users and groups.I previously worked on the provisioning api and which is now deprecated. As from the info, Admin Sdk's directory api need to be used. I went to the links that were given but i couldnt find any sample client to start working on the directory api. Please guide me on to get the info or a sample client to start with

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are right. There is no (Admin SDK) Directory API sample to follow ([list of API samples](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs))

If I were you I'd follow the [Service Account sample code](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts) (I guess that it's what you need to use)

Then you can learn how the [client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/admin/directory_v1) works looking at the other samples and use it following the [Directory API reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/)

EDIT:

Example of user password reset:

```
User user = service.users().get(username + '@' + domainName).execute();
user.setHashFunction("SHA-1");
user.setPassword(DigestUtils.sha1Hex(newPassword));
service.users().update(username + '@' + domainName, user).execute();
```

Comment: Thanks AMS.. I am going through that sample program. If u have any reference on the way to manage users using directory api.please suggest us.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some usage. I'm not gonna spoon-feed you with samples, so I'd recommend you to get a good IDE (w/ autocomplete) and play with the client.

Comment: Hi AMS.. i worked on that client and able to manage users. But i have a question. when i run the code it navigates to a google login page and asks for credentials. can we do it in the client itself by giving the credential without going to UI Login page?? is it possible?

Comment: That's why Service Accounts are in place. I already said that you should be using that on my answer and even pointed you towards a Java sample code on how to obtain a GoogleCredential object. Please read carefully this (https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts) which will tell you how to set up a service account in the Cloud Console.